# Token supply doesn't update after burning them

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, contract-debugging

I made this contract and after I burn my tokens the amount stays the same. The only time they update is when I transfer some amount of tokens to someone's account.
Also on Ropsten scan network and in Mist total supply is totally non synced even though Mist is syncing just fine.

Here is my contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract MyCoin {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name = "MyCoin";
    string public symbol = "XYZ";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 initialSupply = 50000000;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function MyCoin() public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[this] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        //name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        //symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(this, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[this] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[this] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(this, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

/******************************************/
/*       ADVANCED TOKEN STARTS HERE       */
/******************************************/

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, MyCoin {

    uint256 public sellPrice = 500;
    uint256 public buyPrice = 500;
    uint256 private endTime = 1516060799; //@TODO

    uint256 private phaseOneStart = 14512864000; //@TODO
    uint256 private phaseOneEnd = 1413036800; //@TODO

    uint256 private phaseTwoStart = 1513067359; //@TODO
    uint256 private phaseTwoEnd = 1513110559; //@TODO

    uint256 private xmasStart = 1513081759; //25.12.2017 00:00:00
    uint256 private xmasEnd = 1513114159;   //25.12.2017 23:59:59
    uint256 private newyearStart = 1514764800;  //1.1.2018 00:00:00
    uint256 private newyearEnd = 1514851199;    //1.1.2018 23:59:59

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken() MyCoin() public {}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] > _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        owner.transfer(this.balance);                       //send balance to the owner
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function () payable public {

        //this is minimum what you can buy
        require(msg.value >= 1 / buyPrice);

        //ICO has to be active
        require(now < endTime);

        //get amount of tokens to send to the seller
        uint amount = calculateAmount(msg.value);
        uint bonus = getBonus(amount);

        //Xmas or NewYear give them 50% more tokens
        //uint bonus = ;

        _transfer(this, msg.sender,  amount + bonus);
    }

    /**
     * Get bonus for Xmas and New Year
     */
    function getBonus(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        if((now >= xmasStart && now <= xmasEnd) || (now >= newyearStart && now <= newyearEnd)) { //@TODO pripremi vrijeme, dodaj jos koji random dan za popuste
            return _amount * 50 / 100;
        }  else {
            return 0;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Calculate how mush XYZ you need to send
     */
    function calculateAmount(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        //phase 1 (10 days)
        if(now >= phaseOneStart && now <= phaseOneEnd) { //@TODO
            // calculates the amount
            return _amount * buyPrice + (_amount * buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        } 
        //phase 2 (15 days)
        else if (now >= phaseTwoStart && now <= phaseTwoEnd) { //@TODO
            return _amount * buyPrice;
        } 
        //phase 3 (20 days)
        else {
            return _amount * buyPrice - (_amount * buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        }
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which function you are calling to burn the tokens, but if it is `burn()` then you probably want to use `msg.sender` rather than `this` as the account address.  `this` refers to the contract itself, and as it stands this function will only burn tokens owned by the token contract, which is probably not what is intended.

Comment: @FosAvance:  Although unrelated to the problem, there's a huge vulnerability in there. Basically anyone can call burn() to burn the tokens the contract owns. :o

Comment: They can if they have proper information?
It should be like this?
```function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public returns (bool success)```

There is another function called: ```burnFrom```

Comment: No, adding the onlyOwner modifier will prevent people from burning their tokens, if they want so. You should change balanceOf[this] to balanceOf[msg.sender] so whoever calls the function burns their own tokens.